# Using preprocessor defined during compilation time

Tags: makefile, autoconf

I want to define a preprocessor in compile time so that I can use it like this in the code

```
#ifdef MYFLAG
do some thing
#endif
```

I added that flag using AC_DEFINE([MYFLAG], [1], [My Flag]) in configure.ac and ran autoreconf. I can see it defined in configure file but still I can not use it.

Comment: You probably have to `#include` some Autoconf-generated header, like `config.h` or whatever.

Comment: What Kaz said, at least if you are generating a `config.h` -- which you should be.